# How to I get rid of Console Warning: expo-app-loading is deprecated in favour of expo-splash-screen?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo

I keep getting this error that says:

expo-app-loading is deprecated in favour of expo-splash-screen

Here's the code for my Splash Screen in App.js

```
export default function App() {

  const [IsReady, SetIsReady] = useState(false);

  const LoadFonts = async () => {
    await useFonts();
  };

  if (!IsReady) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={LoadFonts}
        onFinish={() => SetIsReady(true)}
        onError={() => {}}
      />
    );
  }

  SplashScreen.hideAsync();
  setTimeout(SplashScreen.hideAsync, 2000);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer style={styles.container}>
   <UserStack/>
   </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this solve your issue?
[How to load custom fonts with the useFonts hook in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77172404)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the expo documentation, you should try something like this, using [expo-splash-screen](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/splash-screen/)

```js
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Entypo from '@expo/vector-icons/Entypo';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';

export default function App() {
  const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function prepare() {
      try {
        // Keep the splash screen visible while we fetch resources
        await SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
        // Pre-load fonts, make any API calls you need to do here
        await Font.loadAsync(Entypo.font);
        // Artificially delay for two seconds to simulate a slow loading
        // experience. Please remove this if you copy and paste the code!
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
      } catch (e) {
        console.warn(e);
      } finally {
        // Tell the application to render
        setAppIsReady(true);
      }
    }

    prepare();
  }, []);

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (appIsReady) {
      // This tells the splash screen to hide immediately! If we call this after
      // `setAppIsReady`, then we may see a blank screen while the app is
      // loading its initial state and rendering its first pixels. So instead,
      // we hide the splash screen once we know the root view has already
      // performed layout.
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [appIsReady]);

  if (!appIsReady) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <View
      style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}
      onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
      <Text>SplashScreen Demo! </Text>
      <Entypo name="rocket" size={30} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

First install with `expo install expo-splash-screen`

You can also configure your app with a SplashScreen from the start with

`npx create-react-native-app -t with-splash-screen.`

Comment: Can you help me out? Thanks

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74361393/how-solve-warning-expo-app-loading-is-deprecated-in-favor-of-expo-splash-screen

Comment: If you use navigation make sure to wrap everything in a View for the `onLayout` prop. The `onLayoutRootView` prop from a Navigation Container does not work with it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you are using a google font via '@expo-google-fonts', your code should look like that :

```js
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import React, { useCallback, useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useFonts, Karla_300Light, Karla_400Regular, Karla_600SemiBold, Karla_800ExtraBold } from '@expo-google-fonts/karla';

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync(); // Keep the splash screen visible while we fetch resources


function App() {
  
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    Karla_300Light,
    Karla_400Regular,
    Karla_600SemiBold,
    Karla_800ExtraBold,
    Caveat_700Bold,
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    async function prepare() {
      await SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
    }
    prepare();
  }, []);

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (fontsLoaded) {
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [fontsLoaded]);

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <NavigationContainer 
        theme={navigationTheme}
        onReady={onLayoutRootView}
      >
          {user ? <AppNavigator /> : <AuthNavigator />}
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a package that has been deprecated by expo and you have to switch to a more recent package.

Delete any code that is related to `expo-app-loading` package [check this](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/app-loading/) ,  and use `expo-splash-screen` instead [check this](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/splash-screen/)