# How solve Warning: expo-app-loading is deprecated in favor of expo-splash-screen: use SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync() instead?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, splash-screen

I am getting below error

```
expo-app-loading is deprecated in favor of expo-splash-screen: use SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync() and SplashScreen.hideAsync() instead. https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/splash-screen/
```

How can I solve this? Can Anyone help me out? My code is as follows

```js
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading'
import React from 'react'
import { ActivityIndicator, ScrollView } from 'react-native'
import EStyleSheet from 'react-native-extended-stylesheet'
import * as Sentry from 'sentry-expo'

import { Navigator } from './navigator'

const styles = EStyleSheet.create({
  scrollView: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: '20rem',
  },
})

class Test extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
  }

  render = () => {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return (
        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollView}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
          <AppLoading onError={this.handleError} onFinish={this.handleFinish} startAsync={this.startAsync} />
        </ScrollView>
      )
    }
    return <Navigator />
  }

  handleError = (error) => {
    Sentry.captureException(error)
  }

  handleFinish = () => {
    this.setState({
      loading: false,
    })
  }

  startAsync = async () => {
    return Promise.all([ ... ])
  }
}

export { Test }
```

I have tried to solve this as in this [How to I get rid of Console Warning: expo-app-loading is deprecated in favour of expo-splash-screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72595258/how-to-i-get-rid-of-console-warning-expo-app-loading-is-deprecated-in-favour-of) but not geeting how to do this.Can any one help me out?

Comment: Does this solve your issue?
[How to load custom fonts with the useFonts hook in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77172404)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the latest module.

Instead of using AppLoading, you need to [create a splash screen image](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/splash-screens/)

Then you can use the [new splash screen method](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/splash-screen/) to show the splash screen until your resources are finished loading.

I would advise taking a look at [this article](https://dev.to/subdeveloper/migrating-from-class-components-to-react-hooks-4lp3) for moving over to the latest in React and React Native. Also there is a more specific to React Native article [here](https://jonathan-holloway.medium.com/react-native-and-migrating-to-hooks-21f9995c3d73)

Here is an example:

```js
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Entypo from '@expo/vector-icons/Entypo';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';

// Keep the splash screen visible while we fetch resources
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function App() {
  const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function prepare() {
      try {
        // Pre-load fonts, make any API calls you need to do here
        await Font.loadAsync(Entypo.font);
        // Artificially delay for two seconds to simulate a slow loading
        // experience. Please remove this if you copy and paste the code!
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
      } catch (e) {
        console.warn(e);
      } finally {
        // Tell the application to render
        setAppIsReady(true);
      }
    }

    prepare();
  }, []);

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (appIsReady) {
      // This tells the splash screen to hide immediately! If we call this after
      // `setAppIsReady`, then we may see a blank screen while the app is
      // loading its initial state and rendering its first pixels. So instead,
      // we hide the splash screen once we know the root view has already
      // performed layout.
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [appIsReady]);

  if (!appIsReady) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <View
      style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}
      onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
      <Text>SplashScreen Demo! </Text>
      <Entypo name="rocket" size={30} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

In this, instead of using your `handleFinish()` and

```
this.setState({
   loading: false,
})
```

You can use something like

```
setAppIsReady(true);
```